# HTML onclick doesn't trigger my function, just nothing happens

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

so I can not find an answer to why this is not working. Everything seems like it should run, but when I click on the button, nothing happens. Please help me solve this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Next Article</title>
    <style>div{width:600px; text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em} article{border: 2px solid blue; padding: 2em; margin: 1em}</style>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="next-article.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<div><button onclick="showNext()">Show Next Article</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript file:

```
/* eslint-env jquery */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
function getArticleGenerator (articles) {
  let contentHolder = $('#content')

  return function () {
    if (articles.length > 0) {
      let article = $('<article>')
      article.append($(`<p>${articles.shift()}</p>`))
      contentHolder.append(article)
    }
  }
}

let articles = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e'
]
let showNext = getArticleGenerator(articles)
```

Comment: showNext is not a function

Comment: remove the `let` before `showNext`

Comment: showNext is a function, the generator returns one

Answer (score 0):

The next a working script. Because `let` sets variable block scoped it was not accessible.

```js
function getArticleGenerator (articles) {
  let contentHolder = $('#content')

  return function () {
    if (articles.length > 0) {
      let article = $('<article>')
      article.append($(`<p>${articles.shift()}</p>`))
      contentHolder.append(article)
    }
  }
}

let articles = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e'
]
var showNext = getArticleGenerator(articles)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div><button onclick="showNext()">Show Next Article</button></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying hjelp me guys, but this "let" isn't the issue, I still can not run the code through my webstorm. Seems like the problem may not be with the code :(

Comment: do have some kind of error messages in your console? or maybe webstorm console if ther is a such(i don't use webstorm)

Comment: The problem seems to be in the html somewhere, not the .js file. It is just that the when I click on the button - nothing happens, no matter what function I attach to it. What could this possibly mean?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the solution :D

```js
function getArticleGenerator (articles) {
  let contentHolder = $('#content')

  return function () {
    if (articles.length > 0) {
      let article = $('<article>')
      article.append($(`<p>${articles.shift()}</p>`))
      contentHolder.append(article)
    }
  }
}

let articles = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e'
]
showNext = getArticleGenerator(articles)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div><button type="button" onclick="showNext()">Show Next Article</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. However I do not understand why it works like this.
First I have noticed that when I use internally in the html my function works, so I tried with the script moved down in the body and voila it works. However Iwould really like to understand why is that. Especially sence it seems that on some other guys computers my initial code works. So what is going on here? Thanks in advance to whoever explains this mystery to me. Here is how I changed my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Next Article</title>
    <style>div{width:600px; text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em} article{border: 2px solid blue; padding: 2em; margin: 1em}</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="next-article.js"></script>
<div><button onclick="showNext()">Show Next Article</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your generator function was called immediately in the script file, and the `content` div wasn't loaded yet when the script was placed in the `head`.

Comment: But why does the previous code work on other guys computers?